# How to convert file name to a searchable name in database?

Tags: php

I have a list of songs in my database but they appear as file like for example song_tile.wav. How  can I add a file to where its searchable and still plays the file in a music app? I think the problem is in the 3rd value in str_replace. I don't know if its the correct value because its printing the file with .wav in my database. Any suggestions?

```
// Scan Directory for musicfiles
$musicfiles = glob('*.wav');


usort ($musicfiles, function($a, $b) {
  return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});

$file = str_replace(".wav", "", $musicfiles);
$file = str_replace("_", "", $musicfiles);

//insert list of files to database IF they dont exist
foreach ($musicfiles as $file) {
 $trackname = basename("$file");
 echo $trackname."*";
 $addquery = "INSERT INTO song (id, trackname, year, numlikes, numplays, artist_id, genre_id, album_id) VALUES (default, '$trackname', '2020', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1')";
 mysqli_query($con, $addquery);
 $musicfiles++;
 }
```

Comment: If you remove the file extension the device won't know what type of file it is to be able to choose the appropriate application for it. Why don't you just store the file name in one column and an identifier in another?

Comment: the commands are not a combination, maybe would be $file = str_replace(".wav", "", $musicfiles);
$file = str_replace("_", "", $file);

Comment: @JohnConde You have a point, I did conceder that but I want a user to be able to search the song without the extension will the song and it still player the file. Is that possible?

Comment: You can store the song name in one column (Cool Song Name) and the file name in another (cool_song_name23.wav), like what @JohnConde said

Comment: @AntonioAbrantes That still echos the extension

Comment: @afghanimah Ok will I still be able to search that Cool Song Name and play cool_song_name23.wav?

Comment: Yes, you can select the filename column even if you're just comparing against the songname column

Comment: @afghanimah Ok, Thank you!

Comment: when you do $trackname = basename("$file"); you reinserted extensions

Comment: if  you want skip extension after it you should do  $trackname = str_replace(".wav", "", $trackname );